# TimeoutError Error while sending email using Django and SMTP protocol

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I have a Django project and an app inside the project. Now I am trying to send email using SMTP. But when I am trying send email it's showing this error:

**TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond**

The configuration for sending email in settings.py is :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "MyEmailId" 
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "MyPass"
```

The code for sending email in views.py is :

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail(
'email_subject',
'email_body',
'MyEmailId',
['ReceiverEmailId'],
fail_silently=False,
)
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Have you generated the app password on your Gmail account? This is not to be mistaken with the password you use to log into your gmail account.

Comment: Sorry. I can't understand. Which app password?